# Web API call returned 404 from DNN site

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

First of all sorry If I am wrongly asking this question on SO. I have a third party library (`[Link][1]`) where the Web API logic has been written. I have a DNN Custom module from where I show the PDF viewer. But when loading the Viewer I get `404` exception for this call `http://dnndev.me/dvapi3/docuvieware3api/init/1`.

I am not sure from where the problem is happening exactly whether in DNN or in the third party tool. Any help to this problem will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

**WebAPI Controller MetaData**

```
namespace GdPicture14.WEB
{
public class DocuVieware3ApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    public DocuVieware3ApiController();
    [System.Web.Http.ActionNameAttribute("init")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute]
    public string init([System.Web.Http.FromBodyAttribute] object jsonString);
}
}
```

**RouteMapper.cs**

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using GdPicture14.WEB;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DocumentViewer
{
public class RouterMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute(
        "DocumentViewer",
        "default",
        "{controller}/{action}",
        new string[] { "DocumentViewer" });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your controller doesn't inherit from the DnnApiController or any other DNN helper so I don't see how this issue could be specific to DNN.

Comment: @Mickers: `DocuVieware3ApiController`is third party controller which inherits `System.Web.Http.ApiController` and I cannot edit/update that library. Is there anything that all API's called from DNN modules should inherit `DnnApiController`??

Answer (score 0):

I've got an example of API calls available in a DNN module in my [VehiDataCollector module](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/VehiDataCollector)

You need to provide [a route mapper](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/VehiDataCollector/blob/master/Services/VehiDataCollectorRouteMapper.cs)

```
 public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("VehiDataCollector","Default", "{controller}.ashx/{action}",
                                 new[] { "Christoc.Modules.VehiDataCollector.Services" });

        //mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyServices", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new {"MyServices"});
    }
```

Then [a controller that inherits from DnnApiController](http://public%20class%20VehiDataCollectorController%20:%20DnnApiController%20%20%20%20%20%7B) like @Mickers points out in the comments

```
 public class VehiDataCollectorController : DnnApiController
    {
        //URL to get the list of vehicles

        [HttpGet]
        //[DnnAuthorize()]
        //TODO: make it so we can call without ModuleId to get a list of vehicles
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetVehicles()
        {
            try
            {
                var mc = new ModuleController();
                var mi = mc.GetModuleByDefinition(0, "VehiDataCollector"); 
//TODO: assuming PortalId=0 if moduleid =0 
                return GetVehicles(mi.ModuleID); 
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                DnnLog.Error(exc); //todo: obsolete
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Module Not On A Page, or No Vehicles Exist"); //todo: probably should localize that?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean all my API controllers including third party library API's inside Dnn MUST BE inherited from `DnnApiController` NOT `System.Web.Http.ApiController` ??

Comment: Perhaps not, but you definitely need to use the routemapper so that DNN knows it exists.

Comment: I already have `RouteMapper.cs` from my DNN custom module. I have created sample WebAPI and can access the Web API action method but NOT third party library API method.